# can anybody tell or recommend a video series for java threads and help me out to fix an error?

Tags: java, multithreading

[Code fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcPlu.png)

I followed a video series of Derek Banas about java threads but applying the same code on my compiler it gave me an error. I dont know why.please help me out.

[Another code fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp8lV.png)

note: I have already defined "getTheMail" with an integer.

Comment: `getTheMail()` requires no parameter, so just remove the `5`

Comment: This is not a threading issue. You should instantiate ```GetTheMail``` class without giving any constructor parameters since it is not expecting any.. like this : ```new GetTheMail();```

Comment: Also have a look at the java naming conventions

Comment: when seeing your edit you have to use `Runnable getMail = new getTheMail(); getMail.getTheMail(5)`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, but real code fragments. And indicate what the code fragments are meant to do...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a threading issue. You should instantiate `GetTheMail` class without giving any constructor parameters since it is not expecting any.. like this : `new GetTheMail();` I encourage you to read this article for further understanding : https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html